# How to hook visited page/click link?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular6

Is there possable to run some event/method by route visiting.
I need to check each time some data in app.component when user did enter.
There is similar hook called 'ngDoCheck' but it is working also for many other reasons, for ex. by changing any [(ngModel)]

Comment: you just need to run the method on the init method of the component loaded for this route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) which Angular provides. you can create your logic in .ts file and add that CanActivate interface into your route. This way you can perform operations while calling your route.

EDIT

There is also an interface [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) to check for operation on leaving the route.

Comment: for my several routes set canActivate : [AccountGuard]. and I can't understande how I should use single custom CanActivate for all my routes = /

Comment: Yeah. you can use that canActivate : [AccountGuard] for particular routes. I often use this to protect authenticated routes. Whatever route i want to protect, i add this method for that route. And in this method i make conditions to check if user is logged in or not. Then it will return true or redirect to defined page.

Comment: I built some additional class AppEnter/CanActivate, and added one for all my routes. I hope that is right coding. thx / canActivate : [AccountGuard, AppEnter],

Comment: Yes. you can use multiple guards for particular route.